# Why is the data being passed to the serializer saving as null in the database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been working on this Django project with a rest framework serializer to take info sent from the front-end organize it and save it in the database. The info is made by drawing boxes over input fields on forms and sending all the fields you define. However, it's as though the data isn't actually being used after defining DataSerializer(data=data).

An example of request.data = {'TextField': [], 'DateField': [], 'SignatureField': [['FieldName', [129, 79], [138, 35], 'Form.jpg']]}

Here's my serializer:

```
Class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FormData
        fields = ["FieldName", "StartX", "StartY", "width", "height", "JSONData", "FormType"]
    
    def create(self, **validated_data):
        print(**validated_data)
        return FormData.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Here's my post View

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_list(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dataDict = request.data
        
        for info in dataDict:
            Field = dataDict[info]
            stringDict = str(dataDict) 


            for object in Field:
                
                datadict = {
                    "FieldName": object[0],
                    "StartX": object[1][0],
                    "StartY": object[1][1],
                    "width": object[2][0],
                    "height": object[2][1],
                    "JSONData": stringDict,  
                    "FormType": object[3]
                }
                  
        serializer = DataSerializer(data=datadict)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.create()  
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        print(serializer.errors)
            
    return Response("Not Valid")
```

Here's my model which has been modified to accept null values not gonna be the case after I figure this out.

```
class FormData(models.Model):

    FieldName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    StartX = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    StartY = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    JSONData = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    FormType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

While this isn't capable of handling more than one rectangle drawn as an input, I'm just trying to figure out how to handle request.data organize it and save it. However, all I get is Null or absent values in the database with no errors thrown back.

## DeBugging Attempts

When I was trying to figure this out I had a couple of ideas of what the problem was. One was the logic of the for loops defining data as null, but after coding print(serializer.data) after if serializer.is_valid() it returns what I want it to read.

{'FieldName': 'FieldNamedefinedbyuser', 'StartX': 246, 'StartY': 108, 'width': 345, 'height': 80, 'JSONData': "{'TextField': [], 'DateField': [], 'SignatureField': [['asdfasdfsadf', [246, 108], [345, 80], 'Darthvad.jpg']]}", 'FormType': 'Form.jpg'}

So I don't think that could be it. Then I thought maybe the data dictionary needs to be JSON because every other example of create uses DataSerializer(data=request.data), but this also didn't work because it returned an error saying it expects a dictionay but got str code.

Code:

```
Json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
serializer = DataSerializer(data=Json_object)
```

Error:
{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.', code='invalid')]}

Although maybe that's because of the way I'm turning the dictionary into JSON, but request.data doesn't actually seem to be JSON even though I'm sending it through Fetch Api from the javascript end of things. Which may be the problem, but I have no idea.

Additionally, printing **validated_data to the terminal gives me somewhat of an idea to the issue as it is entirely null. So my best guest has to do with how I'm handling the data that's put into the serializer causing some issue. Could I get some direction?

Comment: `validated_data` is a positional argument. you don't have to use `**`, there are no kwargs passed to `create`, that's why it prints out None:  `def create(self, validated_data):`

Comment: @IgorMoraru That makes sense, but when I try it out I just get a type errror: TypeError: DataSerializer.create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'validated_data'

Comment: that's because you should not call directly `create` in view, or you'd have to provide validated_data yourself. Instead, call `save()`, and it will chose to create a new instance or update an existing one, depending on the data you are providing to serializer. In short: `serializer.is_valid() serializer.save()`